# ng serve -o shows blank browser screen

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular, angular7

Actually I'm very beginner to Angular. I was trying to integrate Angular into my existing ASP.NET web forms project.

So what I did is installed NODE.JS.

Installed Angular CLI via

```
>npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Installed typescript into my project using

```
>npm install -g typescript
```

Then created a new app by

```
ng new AngularApp
```

These above parts were executed without any trouble and the new AngularApp part created under my Project Root directory.

From that new AngularApp directory I executed the following command

```
ng serve -o
```

expecting it will open a new browser with Angular 7 demo screen. But it only opened a blank white browser page. Please help me to find what I did wrong.

```
ng --version
Angular CLI : 8.0.2
Node : 10.16.2
```

Also I have another question along with it, do I need to run the serve command whenever some changes been made? Or will it automatically listen to changes in code?

Comment: What does it show when you browse to URL manually?

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam The same.. a blank white window

Comment: Is it just a blank browser tab? or a blank page while browser tab has your application link

Comment: Its showing the same url after compiling in the address bar..
http://localhost:4200/

Comment: Then it looks like there are exceptions in your web app. Use browser inspect tool to resolve the errors. That should solve the problem. It is not related to 'ng' CLI.